# Replace text within mathematical statement and then evaluate

Tags: regex, perl, replace, hashtable

I have a list of statements that I'm reading in from a file, where each statement may contain some text.

```
#define macro_name            macro_value // any comments
```

Here is some sample data:

```
#define CER_PER_REGION        0x0080  // <128> Max CER per DM region
#define TER_PER_BER_REGION    256
#define NO_OF_BER_REGIONS     16
#define ASYMP_LIMIT           0x1200
#define TER_MAX               (TER_PER_BER_REGION * NO_OF_BER_REGIONS)  // TER region where the data pitch is constant
#define TER_FORMAT            ((NO_OF_TER_REGIONS-1)*CER_PER_REGION)+2)  // Regions go across all the CER surfaces

#define SCL_DVT1_CODE_SIZE    (SCL_DVT1_SIZE - SCL_DVT1_TBL_SIZE - SCL_DVT1_DATA_SIZE)    //* these macros are defined in another file, assume they've already been hashed
#define MEMORY_BUDGET_SCREEN  (1   * ((SCREEN_TARGET_SECTOR_SIZE / HOST_SIZE) * MB_SIZE)) //* these macros are defined in another file, assume they've already been hashed
```

I've successfully been able to write a regex that separates '#define', 'macro_name', and 'macro_value' into three variables. My problem lies with replacing the text within the right-hand-side (RHS) of the third variable, `macro_value`, where the text has some value stored in a hashtable as {'macro_value' => actual_value}.

The end goal is to run `eval` on the RHS once all the text has been replaced. For example, `TER_MAX` would look like `(256 * 16)` after replacement, so I would store it as `{"TER_MAX" => 4096}` in my hash.

One idea I had was to iterate over the keys in my hash table and do a `s/$key/$value/`, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

```
sub parseRHS{
   my $expr = shift;
   my %hash = @_;

    while ( my($key, $value) = each %hash){
        print "Old: ".$expr."\n";
        eval "\$expr =~ s/.*{$key}.*/.*{$value}.*/";
        print "New: ".$expr."\n";
        print "\n";
    }
```

}

Could anyone help me? This also isn't the most efficient way of doing this, but I'm not too worried about performance at the moment. But if there is a better approach to going about this, I'm all ears.

Comment: You need just `$expr =~ s/\b$key\b/$value/g`. There is no need to do an `eval` at this point. What do you intend by enclosing the variables in braces? That will form a repetition count in a regex.

Comment: I thought it would act as an escape function so that the phrase '$key' isn't matched on instead of the actual value. But what you suggested works. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this in Perl instead of using a real C preprocessor? This issue came up in your previous question but I don't think you ever addressed it.

Comment: Does it have to be in perl?

Comment: Okay I didn't expect it to be so simple! I've posted my comment as an answer so that others can see that it has been resolved.

Comment: @Borodin A real cpp would remove all instances of the defined macros once it has finished processing, if I understand it correctly. However, I have a linker file that uses these same macros to lay out regions in memory. If I parse them myself, then I can obtain the macro's final values and then perform a simple replace on the macros within the linker file so that ultimately I get the base and size addresses for the memory regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just `$expr =~ s/\b$key\b/$value/g`. There is no need to do an `eval` at this point.